# ngRoute doesn't seem to work. angular 1.5.7

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know there is a few questions on this topic, but none of theme helped me resolved my problem.

I have : 
- 404 error 
- browserLink:37 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. warning

html:

```
<script src="~/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/controller.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/parkingCtrl.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"])

    .config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', 
      function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });

        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";


        $routeProvider.
            when("/parking", {
                template: '/locelec/voiturelist',
                controller: "parkingCtrl",
            });

    }]) 



})(window.angular);
```

1 file

```
angular.module('app').controller('FirstController', function () { });
```

2 file

```
angular.module('app').controller('parkingCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$routeParams', 
  function ($rootScope, $scope, $routeParams) {

}]);
```

have spend all weekend trying to figure out the routing, start to desperate :) Thank you for your help. best regards.

vue :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/locelec/voiturelist">
<div class="page page-dashboard ng-scope" ng-controller="parkingCtrl">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Voitures</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="#/bicycles/new">
        Ajoutez nouveau voiture
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Marque</th>
            <th>Modele</th>
            <th>Carburant</th>
            <th>Numbre de Portes</th>
            <th>Transmission</th>
            <th>Consommation</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="vehicule in model.listvehicules | filter: {TypeVehicule : 'voiture'}">
            <td>{{vehicule.Id}}</td>
            <td>{{vehicule.Marque}}</td>
            <td>{{vehicule.Modele}}</td>
            <td>{{vehicule.Carburant}}</td>
            <td>{{vehicule.NumPortes}}</td>
            <td>{{vehicule.Transmission}}</td>
            <td>{{vehicule.Consommation}}</td>
            <!--<td>
              <a class="btn btn-default" role="button" 
                 ng-link="['VoitureEdit', {id: vehicule.Id}]">
                Edit {{vehicule.Id}}
              </a>
            </td>-->
            <td>
              <a class="btn btn-default" role="button" ng-link="['VoitureEdit']">
                 Edit VoitureEdit
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</script>
```

Comment: 1st one is not a controller its a module. you cant put function in that.

Comment: What about the template files for the routes?

Comment: I think your templateUrl is not right, Try this `when("/parking", {
                templateUrl: "./app/voiture-list.component.html",
                controller: "parkingCtrl",
            });`

Comment: it isn't working. I'm inside .NET MVC5.

Comment: Change 'template' to 'templateUrl' and add the correct path to the html document (app/PATH//locelec/voiturelist.html'. I've never tried binding a tempalte by id is that even possible? Also in your view remove 'ng-controller="parkingCtrl"' as you've already defined the controller on the route.

Comment: It is possible, saw it working!

Answer (score 0):

The key problem was

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

missing.

I realise it with help of this really nice tutorial.[Angularjs route configuration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hThmoKA9aeU)

Thank you all guys !